# Can GruntJS fetch external files?

Tags: css, gruntjs

For example I have `index.css` that contains links to another css files:

```
@import "http://<some_url>/bootstrap.css";
@import "http://<some_url>/plugin.css";
@import "app.css";
```

It is possible to concatenate these files with Grunt JS?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Grunt API, the file stuff appears to apply exclusively to local files.
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file

Furthermore I haven't seen anything in the source code where it parses CSS files looking for imports.

**To get them concatenated together:**

I'd recommend that you download the files locally, put them in your usual css folder then use Grunt concat as normal.

I'd then write a small script using wget to download fresh copies of these dependencies before building with grunt.

Comment: Just FYI... The link is broke now.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this was asked, but I came across it while trying to do something similar.   Here is one way to save a file from a url using a grunt task.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict'; 
  var http = require('http');

  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      scripts: {
        files: ['**/*.cfc'],
        tasks:['saveURL']
      }
    },
    open:{
      error:{
        path:'http://<server>/rest/error.html' 
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');


  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

  grunt.registerTask('saveURL', 'Write stuff to a file', function() {
    var done = this.async();
    var reloadurl = 'http://<server>/rest/index.cfm?rl';

    grunt.log.writeln('Loading URL:' + reloadurl + ' ...');

    http.get(reloadurl, function(res) {
      var pageData = "";
      if(res.statusCode != '200'){
        //if we don't have a successful response queue the open:error task
        grunt.log.error('Error Reloading Application!: ' + res.statusCode);
        grunt.task.run('open:error');
      }
      res.setEncoding('utf8');

      //this saves all the file data to the pageData variable
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        pageData += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', function(){
        //This line writes the pageData variable to a file
        grunt.file.write('error.html', pageData)
        done();
      });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
      done(false);
    });
  });

};
```

Comment: Can you provide an example config that use this task?

Comment: This task has no config options so you can run it like any other task.  'grunt saveURL'